# SQL combined SELECT statement (for SQL zoo)

Tags: sql, select

I was using SQL zoo for brushing up my SQL knowledge and found the following problem:

> "Some countries have populations more than three times that of any of
>   their neighbours (in the same continent). Give the countries and
>   continents."

The solution I have put down for this is:

```
   SELECT name, continent 
   FROM world w
   WHERE NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT *
   FROM world nx
   WHERE nx.continent = w.continent
   AND nx.population <= 3*w.population)
```

The interpreter is saying that I have "too few columns" (on [number 8 problem on SQL zoo](http://www.sqlzoo.net/wiki/SELECT_within_SELECT_Tutorial)). I am not sure what is incorrect here. Any suggestion or help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That page has a "Show correct result" button, which should tell you exactly what's incorrect about the results, if not the SQL statement you used.

When I use your SQL statement for that problem, I get the right columns, but the wrong rows, so I must assume you've typo'd somewhere.

One correct answer for that question is:

```
SELECT name, continent
   FROM world w
   WHERE population IS NOT NULL
   AND NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT * FROM world x
         WHERE x.continent = w.continent
         AND population IS NOT NULL
         AND x.name != w.name
         AND x.population > w.population/3
   )
```